# Join custom Terminal shortcut with Unity launcher icon

Tags: unity, launcher, shortcuts, .desktop

I've created a shortcut on the desktop which launches the terminal with a custom working directory. Here's the content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=CM Terminal
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
Categories=Developoment
Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/name/android/system
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=gnome-terminal
```

This works but now I have two terminal icons in the taskbar on the side. Can I make Unity join these two entries?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, but you don't need to create an additional launcher (`.desktop`file) to do that. You can add the command: `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/name/android/system` to your existing `gnome-terminal`launcher as a quicklist item, available on right-click.

[image]

#### How to do that:

- Copy your global `.desktop` file to the local directory `~/.local/share/applications`:

  ```
  cp /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
  ```

  *[An application's desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` "overrules" the global one. Unless you want the change to be available to all users, it is good practice to edit a local copy instead of the global one.]*
- Open the file with `gedit`:

  ```
  gedit ~/.local/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop
  ```
- Replace the line, starting with: `Actions=`, by:

  ```
  Actions=New;CM Terminal;
  ```
- Add a section at the end of the file:

  ```
  [Desktop Action CM Terminal]
  Name=CM Terminal
  Exec=gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/name/android/system
  OnlyShowIn=Unity;
  ```

Log out and back in and you your entry should be available on right-click

Note:
Looking at your `.desktop` file, by adding the line `StartupWMClass=gnome-terminal`, the launcher you created would "steel" the `gnome-terminal` windows from their original icon in the launcher. New terminal windows would appear under your (second) icon.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. You were right with your note. I'm a beginner regarding Ubuntu and Linux and just messed around a little bit.

Comment: Perfect! Glad it works.